# How can I dynamically display the count of items in a ListBox each time it changes?

Tags: c#, events, listbox

I have a C# project that has a ListBox as part of it's user interface. This ListBox is used to display a number of project names. I also have options that will change the size of this ListBox based on queries to a database (all projects, incomplete, complete, so on).

I also have a label that will display the number of results that are inside the ListBox. I was hoping to find a way to do this automatically each time the list changes, rather than at each line of code where I change the list.

I have tried using the DataSourceChanged event, but this poses a really interesting problem. The event is fired BEFORE the ListBox is actually populated with the new values. For example, at the beginning of the program I set the ListBox's data source to a group of 100 projects. Then, the DataSourceChanged event is fired, and I call `listBox1.Items.Count.ToString()` to get the value, and it returns 0. Again, because the list box hasn't been populated. So I will have a label displaying 0 and a list box of 100 items.

Now, if I were to narrow this down to incomplete projects (which, for example, will have a count of 50), when the event is fired it will return a value of 100. This is because the incomplete projects haven't yet been populated since the datasource changed. So, I will have a label that says 100 but a list box of only 50 items.

Is there another event I can use? Does the DataSourceChanged event have any parameters that I can view the pending data source to get a count? Or should I really find every instance in my code that changes the listbox and update the label there.

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection<T>` to bind with ItemsSource which automatically provide notification to UI for update.

Comment: Instead of firing `listBox1.Items.Count.ToString()` on `DataSourceChanged` you can try to add it to the function what adds the items to the list or what binds the DataSet to the Listbox.

Comment: WPF is not about events. You're using a totally wrong approach. WPF is about XAML and DataBinding, not procedural code. Simply do `<TextBox Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=YourListBox}"/>` and you're good to go. No need for horrible winforms-like hacks.

Comment: Thanks for the great ideas guys. Unfortunately (well, fortunate for me) I'm out of the office on vacation this week and this was for a work project, the source code still on my desktop. Will come back in a week with results, if anyone is interested to check back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the interface ICollectionView for such tasks, which will even make you keep your itemssource intact(Saves your db some workload, and alot of cluttering).
You will also need to use the ObservableCollection for your itemssource as mention in other comments here. Rather than focusing on events in WPF, you should use bindings, commands and the works. Nasty codebehind gives and old MVVM veteran sore eyes and makes small kitties cry ;)

Use the filter when you can, on a complete change of "datasource" you simply change the Stuffs collection. Pardon my naming here, I tried to make the example as easy as possible for you.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="custtest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:custtest="clr-namespace:custtest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <custtest:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stuffs}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></ListBox>
        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding StuffFilterView.Count}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

The code below is very simple, and you should never do what I do there in the ctor! It's just for simplicity.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> stuffs;
    private string searchText;
    private ICollectionView stuffFilterView;

    public ICollectionView StuffFilterView
    {
        get { return stuffFilterView; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, stuffFilterView)) return;
            stuffFilterView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<String> Stuffs
    {
        get { return stuffs; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, stuffs)) return;
            stuffs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String SearchText
    {
        get { return searchText; }
        set
        {
            if (value == searchText) return;
            searchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnSearchTextChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnSearchTextChanged()
    {
        StuffFilterView.Refresh(); // Refresheses content in your ICollectionView when text changes            
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Bad pie!
        Stuffs = new ObservableCollection<string> {"jall", "b", "c", "d", "blabla"};
        StuffFilterView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Stuffs);
        StuffFilterView.Filter = FilterStuff;
    }

    private bool FilterStuff(object obj)
    {
        String str = obj.ToString();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
            return true;

        return str.Contains(SearchText);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] // R# remove if you don't have it
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers, 
Stian

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm going to be away from this project for a week due to a vacation, but I will definitely come back in August with my results. I just didn't want it to appear as if this was being ignored.

Comment: You have all you need right there, have a nice vacation! It isn't really that complicated, but as stated you need to include INot. in all your nested classes and you are up and running. The code above runs if you test it for your self. I just made a real quick app through rdp, as I'm up visiting my relatives my self. ;)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but this is my first time working with xaml files, and I can't seem to find it. Is this a file that should already exist somewhere in visual studio, or is it a file I have to create?

Comment: @McAdam331 It all depends on what template you use for creating your wpf project. I reccomend downloading galasoft mvvm light, and use their templates. Or else you just create a new WPF project. If you mean to create a new WPF window/usercontrol it's just to right click your project, select Add New Item and browse to your wpf window/usercoontrol/cust.ctl/page, or just selected them from the menu New menu directly. Also beware of assemblyinfo.cs in the properties folder if you are making a library. Some lines are commented out, which you need for WPF.

Comment: I figured out what I've done. A long complicated mistake but I am now back on the right track. Thank you again for all your help, really appreciated.